# In Azure Monitor for Application Insights how do you make a bar chart by day in Kusto?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, kusto-explorer, appinsights

In Azure Monitor for Application Insights how do you make a bar chart using a search term where the results are grouped by day?
If you have large logs in Application Insights but want to print a bar chart where they are grouped by day using the Kusto language.

Answer (score 1):

```
// replace "my search term" with yours

union isfuzzy=true
    availabilityResults,
    requests,
    exceptions,
    pageViews,
    traces,
    customEvents,
    dependencies
| where * has "my search term"
| summarize Requests = count() by day = toint(format_datetime(timestamp, 'd'))
| order by day asc
| render barchart
```

### union

This pulls together all the different types of Azure Monitor log records, you can comment some out if you are only looking for traces.

### where

the * operator looks in all the searchable properties inside each element in the union

### summarize

this is the equivalent of a group by statement where we build the x-axis of the bar as the Requests property and then group them by day for the y-axis. The timestamp is converted to a date of the month value (1,2,3...31) and then converted to integer

### order by

order the elements by the day ascending

### render

render by barchart, remember there are Chart Formatting settings next to the Chart in Azure Monitor where you can fine tune the output

### date range

the date range is handled by the Time range control above the Azure Monitor log editor window.

[Visualizations charts](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-visualizations)
[Kusto reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/)